# Haste or no haste? That is the question

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning, proverbs

The proverb **"More haste, less speed"** apparently means:

> You make better progress with a task if you don't try to do it too quickly.
>    [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/more_haste,_less_speed)

What is the difference betwen *'haste'* and *'speed'* in this case? According to the same dictionary, *'haste'* means:

> Excessive speed or urgency of movement or action

Yet if the proverb advocates *more* haste, surely this means even more excessive speed.  Why should one use more haste, which seems counter-intuitive?

Comment: Another way of saying "Haste makes waste".

Comment: See also the phrase, “slow is smooth, smooth is fast”.

Comment: Slow and steady wins the race.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found this confusing too, so I looked it up.

The OED gives a number of sayings, and a number of forms of this expression, including

> The more haste the lesse spede. [1546]
>
> With more hast, then good spede, I brought it to an ende. [1556 - "then" means "than", I believe]

It seems to me from these that the meaning of the phrase, back in the sixteenth century was not "Make haste instead of speed", but "If you make more haste, the result will be less speed". I had never thought of it this way before, and I suspect that few people have.

So while the overall meaning of the proverb has survived, I now think that the understanding of the words has altered, and this is why you find it puzzling.

Comment: So, no procrastination or rushing things at the end?

Comment: Well I suppose that might be a corollary. But it doesn't really talk about procrastination. It just says that if you rush, in the end it will take longer.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haste) adds two more definitions: "_rash or headlong action_" and "_undue eagerness to act_".  Given this, I think yo're analysis is correct in that the real meaning is your 1546 example.

Comment: +1 That is how I have always interpreted the saying—it's a warning, not a suggestion.

Comment: 'It seems to me from these that the meaning of the phrase, back in the sixteenth century was ...' ... exactly the same as it is now, surely? While your understanding may have been at odds with that I don't think it is fair to assume that most people's is.

Comment: Maybe not, @Spagirl. Obviously, if clever old me thought that, then other people must :-( But the score of 10 on this answer suggests to me that other people found it useful.

Comment: #@ColinFine Indeed it does, which is why I haven't down-voted or anything. I was just genuinely surprised by the notion that people presently interpret the meaning as 'make haste instead of speed'.

Answer (score 6):

The saying **more haste, less speed** is suggesting that a focus on speed is sometimes counter-productive.

Sometimes when we do things too quickly we make mistakes and have to do them a second time. In such cases we might have been finished sooner had we not made the first attempt in such a hurry.

*Haste* relates to the manner in which the work is carried out, *speed* relates to the overall time taken for the work. More haste causes a decrease in speed.

Comment: Yes, I know what the idiom means, I was curious as to why *haste* was used, when it has a very similar meaning to speed.  I was after more of an etymological answer (see Colin Fine's, above)

Comment: @marcellothearcane - "Speed" is an objective measure -- you can determine progress by measuring distance traveled, number of widgets produced, etc.  "Haste", on the other hand, is observed in less objective "metrics" -- stuff splashed, dropped on the floor, wrong turns, etc.

Comment: I added an extra sentence to my answer which may help.

Comment: Also, from your original question it wasn't clear that you did understand the idiom. You wrote "Yet if the proverb advocates more haste, ..." (which it doesn't).

Comment: @marcellothearcane The meaning *isn't* that similar. Per the definition you quote, the speed in haste is definitionaly excessive.

Answer (score 1):

The expression does not actually advocate for more haste. Instead, it cautions against hasty action. It is essentially a condensed way of saying "the more hastily you do something, the longer it will take you to finish it".

This expression is memorable because it is an apparent paradox. If we take a basic understanding of the phrase, it simply claims that "faster is slower", which is clearly nonsense. The real meaning in the phrase comes from the connotations attached to the word "haste", and especially its derivatives such as "hasty" and "hastily". Often, these words have negative connotations attached to them which suggest that an action was not just performed quickly, but *too* quickly. The result is that details were missed or the end product is unacceptable, so extra effort must be expended in the end to make up for mistakes.